# Retrofit,Dynamic json whose fields change depending on the parameters into Gson

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit2 and I need to call an API for information. The JSON that the API gives me has dynamic fields which change depending on the parameter values.
Note that I can have any number of parameters. Below is the JSON for the parameters "1","2".

```
{
   "data":{
      "1":{

         "logo":"https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1.png",
         "id":1,
         "name":"Bitcoin",
         "symbol":"BTC",
         "description":"Bitcoin (BTC) is...",
         "date_added":"2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
         "platform":null,
         "category":"coin"
      }
   },
   "2":{
      "logo":"https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1.png",
      "id":1,
      "name":"Bitcoin",
      "symbol":"BTC",
      "description":"Bitcoin (BTC) is...",
      "date_added":"2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "platform":null,
      "category":"coin"
   }
}
```

I've created an interface in which I get the header and the parameter key which then I call later in retrofit to return me the info I need.

```
public interface CurrencyService {
    @GET(ApiConstants.CRYPTOCURRENCYINFO)
    Call<CurrencyService> getCurrencyById(@Header("X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY") 
String appkey,
                                          @Query("id") int[] ints);
}
```

Comment: What are the changes expected in the WEB API @Tiberiu

Comment: @Venky The "1","2" fields from the JSON i gave as example change depending on the parameters that i introduce.For example if my parameters are "3","4","5","6" then i would get 4 dynamic fields ,each having the name "3","4","5","6"  with some info in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CurrencyService {
    Map<String, Data> data;
}

public class Data {
    String logo;
    int id;
    String name;
    String symbol;
    String description;
    String date_added;
    Object platform;
    String category;
}

Call<CurrencyService> getCurrencyById(@Header("X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY")String appkey, @Query("id") int[] ints);
```